# application with nodejs and php rest apis

Tags: php, ios, node.js, chat

we are having requirement for a ios native app with mobile number as uuid and involves other functionalities with chat also.

1. Register mobile number as uuid and create token against it or we can use uuid and mobile binding for notifications.
2. For chat (group / individual) , when we use nodejs server and socket io  client. when creating client, how do we map mobile number
   with that socket at server side.
3. if we use php REST apis for most of the calls, how we integrate php to nodejs calls.

what we are trying to achieve is using PHP REST apis mostly. and use nodejs socketio for chat and realtime notifications. i am looking into multiple examples but not matching the above scenarios.

https://github.com/jdutheil/nodePHP

https://entwickler.de/webandphp/integrating-node-js-with-php-125830.html

http://elephant.io/ (php and socketio)

As our client is ios native app, so we are not sure which way to go for it. Communication between nodejs and PHP is confusion here.[image]

Comment: so do you have a question?

Comment: still on your update you have'nt yet asked any question

Comment: It's not clear on why PHP and NodeJS need to communicate.

Comment: when we do some action like eg. disable user from php rest call we need to send notification to the ios app by nodejs. for this we need to communicate between php and nodejs.\

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile everything in world not add up with question mark. what i am asking for is the way of doing above flow is right and what are alternatives. :)

Comment: Why don't you use nodejs for the REST API as well? [This](https://github.com/mevdschee/js-crud-api) will get you started.